# <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)>

Tags: installation, openssl, emscripten

I'm currently installing emsdk. I was just following the tutorial in their site but got stuck at this command:

```
./emsdk install latest
```

Here is the output:

```
Installing SDK 'sdk-1.38.0-64bit'..
Installing tool 'clang-e1.38.0-64bit'..
The contents of file 'llvm/tag/osx_64bit/emscripten-llvm-e1.38.0.tar.gz' already exist in destination '/Users/user1/Desktop/emsdk/clang/e1.38.0_64bit', skipping.
Done installing tool 'clang-e1.38.0-64bit'.
Installing tool 'node-8.9.1-64bit'..
The contents of file 'node-v8.9.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz' already exist in destination '/Users/user1/Desktop/emsdk/node/8.9.1_64bit', skipping.
Done installing tool 'node-8.9.1-64bit'.
Installing tool 'emscripten-1.38.0'..
Error downloading URL 'https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/archive/1.38.0.tar.gz': <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)>
Installation failed!
```

I already tried upgrading to Python 3 from Python 2.7 as well as upgraded my OpenSSL as per suggestion of some posts here. How can I fix this?

Comment: same issue here, created a reference https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/6548

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  I tried updating openssl on MacOS and using a newer version of python, but it still didn't work.

A hacky work around that worked for me is to download the failing file manually into the zips folder.

For example

```
cd zips
wget https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/archive/1.38.0.tar.gz
```

Then try to install again and it should work.